# Jenkins setup for PHPUnit tests which use Selenium standalone webdriver

Tags: git, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I have PHPUnit end-to-end tests which run using Selenium standalone server. My tests extend PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase and I set the browser using $this->setBrowser ( "chrome"); I want to be able to run these tests everyday. I thought I could use jenkins. Sadly, I have no idea how to configure selenium stand alone webdriver and PHPUnit on it. I came across this link when I was looking http://blog.loftdigital.com/posts/jenkins-ci-and-php . Is is not completely clear from this which plugin to install on jenkins, how to pull from git, etc. If you have come across better links please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to run a certain script everyday the usual approach is a cron job (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/). You shouldn't need a whole CI suite just for that. You might also consider only running your tests when changes occur to your code. This can be accomplished with .git-hooks (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

The actual script you'd write would be pretty similar in either case, 1. Run the tests. 2. Collect the output. 3. Report the output. The advantage of the git-hook approach is you can prevent test breaking code from ever reaching your sever (and therefore your users).

Comment: Might as well make use of the notification integrations if it is available